# Castle Windsor Dynamic Assembly Bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor 3.1.0 in an ASP .NET 4 MVC application, which is giving me an exception in the Application_Start event when container.Register is called.

The exception is "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.". Here's the stack trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
   System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetExportedTypes() +56
   Castle.Core.Internal.ReflectionUtil.GetAvailableTypes(Assembly assembly, Boolean includeNonExported) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\Core\Internal\ReflectionUtil.cs:165
   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromAssemblyDescriptor.<SelectedTypes>b__0(Assembly a) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\FromAssemblyDescriptor.cs:56
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +238
   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\FromDescriptor.cs:160
   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.BasedOnDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\BasedOnDescriptor.cs:530
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:506
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:483
   ProductX.Web.Windsor.Installers.ControllerInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in C:\TeamProjects\CompanyX.ProductX\Mainline\Admin\ProductX.Web\Windsor\Installers\ControllerInstaller.cs:24
   Castle.Windsor.Installer.AssemblyInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\Installer\AssemblyInstaller.cs:56
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:319
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) in c:\BuildAgent\work\5b096cace0fecb1f\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:452
   ProductX.Web.MvcApplication.InitializeWindsor() in C:\TeamProjects\CompanyX.ProductX\Mainline\Admin\ProductX.Web\Global.asax.cs:41
   ProductX.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\TeamProjects\CompanyX.ProductX\Mainline\Admin\ProductX.Web\Global.asax.cs:25

[HttpException (0x80004005): The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9171773
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

Here's how I'm calling Register:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
```

When I build the application in Debug mode, it's fine. When I build in Release mode, the exception above occurrs. I can't find anything about this error through Google. My suspicion is that some .NET 4 restrictions were introduced with how reflection is done on dynamic assemblies, which is being introduced in this situation as a Release build optimisation.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a dynamic assembly being emitted (somehow).  Try adding a filter to ignore dynamic assemblies.  This should work:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Where(t => !t.Assembly.IsDynamic).BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, it's helped me move a step closer. If I use the Where() in that position, I can no longer use the BasedOn() after it, as it's marked Obsolete and resets the query. If I use BasedOn first, and the Where() after it, it then says the Where() is obsolete and will reset the query. Very confusing...

Comment: It did solve the dynamic assembly issue though so I'll mark the question as answered. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to do some reflection and iterate over all assemblies loaded in the AppDomain to find out what is creating the dynamic assembly.  The name of the dynamic assembly should stand out as something like "ahsbzfd" (i.e. random characters).  Peek into that assembly and see what's in it.

Comment: It's being called in the following assembly name: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. What's strange is, you would think that  System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetExportedTypes call from the stack trace is causing that, but works in Debug builds, and there are no changes to the referenced DLLs.

Comment: For reference, the issue reproduced and a workaround: http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-374